# jquery send array of objects

Tags: jquery, ajax, object, post

I have an array of objects...

```
[.main-header: Object, .main-header-free: Object, .sub-header-lunch-price: Object, .sub-header-week: Object, .sub-header-week-week: Object…]
```

One object contains:

```
.main-header: Object
background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box"
color: "rgb(192, 192, 192)"
font-family: "NeutraText-Book"
font-size: "35px"
```

How can I send this with a POST.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: { css: styles, theme_id: {{ $theme->id }} },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.success);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

It currently returns "null", and data in Controller is also null..

```
$theme->css = Input::get('css'); //Null
```

I tried to use dataType JSON, and also serialize, and STRINGIFY, doing json.stringify gave me null too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use contentType as 'application/json'

```
var data={construct your object here};
$.ajax({
         url: Your url here,
         type: "POST",
         contentType: 'application/json',
         data: JSON.stringify(data),
         success: function(data) {
             alert(data.success);
             console.log(data);
         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a stupid answer but I had trouble getting ajax POST info once with serialize(), then I tried serializeArray() and it worked, although I would be unable to explain why.

Also, if you are not sure about all the params, try using jQuery.post. Its use is simplified.